# How can I remove tags from my profile?

Tags: support, tags, profile-page

I was about to manage my account as I detect that there are tags within my account, which are different to the favorite tags.
How can I manage them? There is no `x` like it is for the favorite and ignore tags.

Comment: Are you talking about [these tags](http://stackoverflow.com/users/850884/bjorn-schorre?tab=tags)?

Comment: If you are talking about those tags: noting you can do about those afaik. They are attached to your activity and hold not relation to your favourites.

Comment: Yes, I mean these tags.

Answer (score 4):

Those tags are generated from the questions you answer/ask - your activity creates the list.

You don't need to manage them (although you can by being active on different tags if you want)

They are useful for others when assessing how valuable your answers are, as they can get an indication of what your core expertise areas are.